# When exactly do nullable types throw exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception, nullable

Consider the following code:

```
int? x = null;
Console.Write ("Hashcode: ");
Console.WriteLine(x.GetHashCode());
Console.Write("Type: ");
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType());
```

When executed, it writes that Hashcode is `0`, but fails with `NullReferenceException` in attempt to determine type of `x`.
I know that methods called on nullable types are actually called on underlying values, so I expected program to fail during `x.GetHashCode()`.

So, what is the fundamental difference between those two methods and why doesn't the first of them fail?

Comment: Only difference I can find, is that `GetHashCode` is `virtual`...

Comment: [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) is a handy little tool to help answer these sorts of questions.

Comment: I find it odd that `GetType()` from a `Nullable<int>` returns `System.Int32`, and not `System.Nullable<System.Int32>`.

Comment: Also worth noting `int? x = null` is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<int> x = new Nullable<int>(null)`. So, `x` is an actual object, not a null reference.

Comment: Reference source - https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/nullable.cs - does not in any way show GetType being handled, nor does the documentation detail this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is because `int? x = null;` essentially creates an instance of the value type `System.Nullable<int>`,  with an "inner" `null` value (you can check it via `.HasVaue` Property). When `GetHashCode` is invoked, the override `Nullable<int>.GetHashCode` is the method candidate (since the method is virtual), now we have an instance of `Nullable<int>`, and execute its instance method, perfect.

When invoking `GetType`, the method is non-virtual, so the instance of `Nullable<int>` is boxed to `System.Object` first, according to [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/boxing-nullable-types), and boxed value is `null`, hence the `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: All of this matches the behavior we see, but where is it documented? The page you linked to details how boxing behavior works for `Nullable<T>`, but it doesn't say that `GetType()` will require the boxing operation. I'm guessing we need to find documentation for how inherited methods work on value types to find the relevant pieces.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen that is because `GetType` is defined on `object` instead of `struct`, wich causes an implicit boxing. You can verify by assigning `int? x = 1` and then calling `GetType()`. The result is `System.Int32`, **not** `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen You can read C# language specification section 4.3 "boxing and unboxing" for more details.

Comment: If I type int? x = null; and then I try to read it: x.Value then I am getting exception, not the null "value".  If I check if "x" itself is null, then the answer is positive.

Comment: @Eru I used incorrect expressions in the answer, thanks for point that out.

Comment: @DannyChen Okay, but what should be then correct answer for this?

Comment: @Eru Correct answer for what question?

Comment: @DannyChen x.HasValue this is false; x.GetHashCode is 0; x.GetType  returns System.NullReferenceException; x.GetValueOrDefault() also is 0;  So what else can I do with it?

Comment: @Eru I don't quite understand, let's move the discussion to [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170821/question-50128422), and please describe your questions again there.

Answer (score 17):

To clarify Danny Chen's correct answer:

- `Nullable<T>` is a value type.  The value type consists of a bool, which indicates nullity (false means null) and a T, the value.
- Unlike all other value types, nullable types do not box to a boxed `Nullable<T>`. They box to either a boxed `T` or a null reference.
- A method implemented by a value type `S` is implemented as though it has an invisible `ref S` argument; that is how `this` is passed.
- A method implemented by a reference type `C` is implemented as if there was an invisible `C` argument; that is how `this` is passed.
- The interesting case is then a virtual method defined in a reference base class and overridden by a struct that inherits from the base class.

Now you have enough information to deduce what happens. `GetHashCode` is virtual **and overridden by `Nullable<T>`** so when you call it, you call it as though there was an invisible `ref Nullable<T>` argument for `this`.  No boxing happens.

`GetType` is not virtual and so cannot be overridden and is defined on `object`. Therefore it expects an `object` for `this`,  When called on a `Nullable<T>` the receiver must be boxed, and therefore can box to null, and therefore can throw.

If you called `((object)x).GetHashCode()` then you'd see an exception.

Comment: The third and fourth bullet points about the invisible `ref S` and `C` are a bit unclear. Can you expand on them?

Comment: @Nisarg: Just that when you have `class C { void M(int x) { ... } }` and you have `C c = new C(); c.M(123);` then somehow `c` has to become `this` inside `M`.  The way that happens is the call is logically the same as if you had `class C { static void M(C _this, int x) { ... }} ` and a call `C.M(c, 123)`.  `this` is logically *just another argument*. Similarly for structs, except for structs `this` is a `ref` alias to a variable.

Answer (score 5):

The implementation of `Nullable<T>.GetHashCode()` is as follows:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    if (!this.HasValue)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return this.value.GetHashCode();
}
```

So, when the value is null, it will always get you `0`.

`x.GetType()` is same as `null.GetType()` which will throw `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: so, GetHashCode is called on Nullable, not on value it contains? Why so?

Comment: Why is `x.GetType()` the same as `null.GetType()` since in reality you have `(struct).GetType()` ? `Nullable<T>` is a struct, value type.

Comment: Can you also post the implementation of `GetType` just in case if it adds more detail to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like GetHashCode has got a null check. (Used JetBrains to view defenition)

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  if (!this.hasValue)
    return 0;
  return this.value.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: The implementation of `GetHashCode()` only comes into play once it's established that `GetHashCode()` can be called at all though.